# ESLint is not aware of components of Element UI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, eslint, element-ui

I am using Vue.js and Element UI. When I use Element UI components such as `Input` or `Col`, ESLint argues `invalid-end-tag` as below.

I already set `eslint-plugin-vue`, so why is ESLint not aware of custom components?
Is there any way to solve this error?

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Input
      v-model="formLogin.username"
      type="text"
      size="large"
      @on-enter="handleLogin"
    >
    <Icon
      slot="prepend"
      type="ios-person-outline"
    />
    </Input>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
Parsing error: x-invalid-end-tag. eslint(vue/no-parsing-error) [13, 5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) or [`<col>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col) are Element UI components.

They are both native HTML tags and they are both self-closing tags that can't be used that way.

- Element UI uses [`<el-input>`](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input), not `<input>`.
- Element UI uses [`<el-col>`](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/layout), not `<col>`.
- To prepend an icon in `<el-input>`, use the `prefix-icon` prop or `prefix` slot shown below

A correct example:

```html
<el-row>
  <el-col :span="12">
    <el-input
      v-model="input"
    >
      <i slot="prefix" class="el-input__icon el-icon-user"></i>
    </el-input>
  </el-col>
</el-row>
```

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      input: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, my question was wrong. Those were 'iview' components, not 'Element UI' components. What I've found is that such eslint issues for iview components is not fixed, so I had to add custom rules in `.eslintrc`. https://github.com/iview/iview/issues/2828

Comment: Interesting, first time I've heard of iView.  What a bad idea to name a component the same as a native tag though.